# Android GridView Section Header as in iOS

Tags: android, gridview

I am using many gridviews and I want to add section headers as in iOS.
What is the best way for me?

Thanks

Comment: Please be more specific, provide an image of what you are trying to achieve and describe what you have tried so far.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/a81e1c6oj0954sd/Simulator%20Screen%20Shot%20Apr%2020%2C%202016%2C%2011.07.08%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: Unfortunatly there are no section headers in this Screenshot. If you are referring to the text below each image you will need to create custom child layouts for your GridView.

Answer (score 0):

Create a layout for each child view of your GridView, you can add the ImageView and a TextView to resemble the screenshot.

Comment: Please check the screenshot. The banner is implemented as Section header in iOS.